# Sending "tekken+4:*" to `to_tsquery(?)` doesn't match the record with Name "Tekken 4"

Tags: postgresql, full-text-search

I have a record with `name` equal to `"Tekken 4"`.

The search for `"tekken+4:*"` doesn't return any results.

The search for `"seki:*"` returns results `"Sekiro"`.

The search for `"watch+dog:*"` returns results `"Watch Dogs: Legion"`.

How can I fix this query so both queries return results.

```
"to_tsvector('english', name || ' ' || slug) @@ to_tsquery(?)"
```

Comment: Note that full text search doesn't work very well with names.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change my search to:

`"tekken & 4:*"`

Now all cases work as expected.

Comment: Perhaps `to_tsquery('english', 'tekken <-> 4:*')` would be even better.

Comment: Can you expand why it would be better thanks for your help!

Comment: `tekken <-> 4:*` means "`tekken`, immediately followed by something that starts with `4`".